# Matplotlib colorbar in multiple plots and it's placement

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to plot 2 subplots and with colorbars for each of them. I have written the following code-

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2,figsize = (9,6))
fg1 = ax[0].scatter(no_trans["S1_ALL_DEM"].values, no_trans["Del_CAD"].values, c=no_trans["alpha"], cmap = "Set1", alpha=0.4 )
fg2 = ax[1].scatter(no_trans["S1_ALL_DEM"].values, no_trans["Del_CAD"].values, c=no_trans["alpha"], cmap = "Set1", alpha=0.4 )
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(fg1)
cbar1.ax.set_ylabel('alpha', labelpad=20, rotation =-90, fontsize = 12)

cbar2 = plt.colorbar(fg2)
cbar2.ax.set_ylabel('alpha', labelpad=20, rotation =-90, fontsize = 12)
ax[0].set_xlabel("DEM S1")
ax[0].set_ylabel("Del CAD")
ax[0].set_xlim(0,50)
ax[0].invert_yaxis()
ax[1].set_xlabel("DEM S1")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Del CAD")
ax[1].set_xlim(50,35000)
ax[1].invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

I need to fix the colorbars side by side with both of them, how can I do that?

Comment: For this particular application, the 2 colorbars look to be identical.  Why not just have 1 for both subfigures?

Comment: Could you clarify where you want each colorbar? For example, it seems like maybe you want one of them next to each subplot? Or do you want them next to each other on the right but just spaced out better?

Comment: I wanted only one colorbar but it shrinks the 2nd plot. So I thought to make one for each plot.

Comment: To avoid reducing the space available to show the data, I suggest that you do not show two identical colorbars. Try removing `cbar2` and making the following change: `cbar1 = plt.colorbar(fg1, ax=ax)`. Adding `ax` will resize both axes instead of just ax[1], as described in the docstring.